# Why is London real time different from the server time set to...London UTC+0?

Tags: php, apache, timezone

I have a really curious question for you about timezones...

This is what I did via PHP

```
<?php

echo date_default_timezone_get (); 

//prints Europe/London (the timezone is set to London's one)

echo date('G:i A');

//prints 14:43 PM

?>
```

Searching on Google and other websites related to timezones the result is:

14:18

So why PHP says **14:43** whereas Google and the others say **14:18**?

There is a difference of **25** minutes!!

Comment: have you checked server time directly? maybe it's off-time

Comment: Unless you have network time turned on, like NTP usually is for servers, your clock could have drifted considerably from real time.

Comment: Also note that in the summer, London is one hour ahead of UTC anyway... that's not relevant *today*, but it could be for someone reading this question next year. The difference would never be 25 minutes though.

Comment: timezone problems would show differences in (mostly) 60 minute blocks, or (occasionally) 30 minute blocks. 25 minutes is probably your server's clock is innacurate.

Comment: @MarcB: Or 15 minutes for Nepal (and possibly others)...

Comment: man but politicians like to mess with such simple concepts...

Comment: Thank you! The server's time was not synchronized like you said!